# Compare two lists and return match percentage while considering order

Tags: python, list, percentage

I'm trying to write a program in Python that compares a list of inputs with an existing list then returns the match percentage between the two lists, as if it was verifying answers to an exam.

```
print ('Please answer the 20 questions with a, b, c, d or e\n')

correct = ('a','c','d','d','e','b','c','c','a','b','d','c','b','e','c','b','a','e','b','c') #correct answers
answers = [] #empty list that receives the inputs

n = 20
for i in range (0,20):
    ele = input('Insert answer of question %d: ' % (i + 1)) #loop to insert answers into empty list

    answers.append(ele)

overlap = len(set(correct)&set(answers)) / float(len(set(correct)|set(answers))) * 100
print(overlap) #prints percentage obtained
```

Currently it only checks if the answer is somewhere in the correct list, I need to make it compare each matching index instead.

Comment: so what is the problem, exactly? Did you try iterating over both lists and comparing each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the two lists in parallel, counting the number of times they match.

```
correct_count = sum(a == b for a, b in zip(correct, answers))
overlap = correct_count / len(answers) * 100
```